# How to export multiple set of regressions into one Excel workbook using either outreg2 or esttab?

Tags: excel, stata

I have multiple sets of regressions that need to be presented in different tables. I wonder if there is a way to export multiple set of regressions into one Excel workbook using either `outreg2` or `esttab` or some other package?

For example, I run 100 regressions using `esttab`; then I want to present them in 25 different tables with four regressions in each table. The following format of code allows me to export to 25 different csv files:

```
esttab using "$output\output1.csv", se stats(N ymean r2_a) replace
```

However, I want to have all the 25 tables in one workbook with 25 tabs. It is possible to copy-paste the tables if the number of output files is not big, but that's not the case for me.

Comment: Is there a reason for wanting (_e.g._) 25 different tabs with 4 regressions in each tab, rather than a single tab with 100 regressions? Have you looked into the `ctitle()` option of `outreg2` to differentiate your models programmatically? Putting this aside, so far as I know, `outreg2` does not allow one to specify the sheet name(s) in the Excel output file directly (as `outreg2` seems to be based on `outsheet`). However, it is likely possible with the `dta` option and Stata's newer `export excel` command.

Comment: @brendan Because I want to create 25 separate tables. It would be easy to do so if I can export them into 25 tabs, because then I can use an excel macro to format the tables in the way I want. If there is a way in stata that can create 25 tabs, that will be much easier for me to create tables.

Comment: Fair enough. See the answer below for `outreg2`. (I haven't used `esttab`.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `outreg2`, you'll need to use the `dta` option to save the results as individual datasets, and then use the `export excel` command to export each dataset to an individual sheet in the same tab. *E.g.*:

```
clear all
sysuse auto

regress price mpg
outreg2 using "price" , replace dta

regress price mpg headroom
outreg2 using "price" , dta

regress mpg weight length
outreg2 using "mpg" , replace dta

regress mpg weight length foreign
outreg2 using "mpg" , dta

use price_dta
export excel using "results" , sheet("price")

use mpg_dta
export excel using "results" , sheet("mpg")
```

Obviously running this as a loop will make more sense, and you may want to add the `replace` option to the *first* use of `outreg2`. Further use of `outreg2`'s options will help clean up the output further.

Answer (score 2):

`regsave` might be another alternative (info [here](http://econpapers.repec.org/software/bocbocode/s456964.htm) and [here](http://www.stata.com/meeting/boston10/boston10_reif.pdf))

You could easily combine four regressions into one `dta` file and then export them to `xls`.

Some rudimentary code, borrowing from help file, to get you up and running:

```
sysuse auto.dta, clear

regress price mpg trunk headroom length
regsave mpg trunk using results, table(OLS_stderr, order(regvars r2)) replace

regress price mpg trunk headroom length, robust
regsave mpg trunk using results, table(Robust_stderr, order(regvars r2)) append

use results, clear

outsheet using table.txt, replace
export excel using "excell", firstrow(variables) replace
```

If you want to manipulate the Excel output even more, you might also try to harness the power of `xml_tab` package (Check [here](https://ideas.repec.org/c/boc/bocode/s456760.html) and [here](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0037))